# how do I use nls to estimate parameters?

Tags: r, simulation, data-fitting

I want to estimate e50 e0 emax from emax model 
the equation is Y=E0 + ((DOSE * EMAX)/(DOSE + ED50))
I want to use default algorithm
How can I estimate E0 EMAX and E50?

I found the example code is :

```
args(nls)
function (formula, data = parent.frame(), start, control = nls.control(),
algorithm = c("default", "plinear", "port"), trace = FALSE,
subset, weights, na.action, model = FALSE, lower = -Inf,
upper = Inf, ...)
NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: So ... where is your data?

Comment: That's not example code, that's just the signature of the function. There should be examples on the `?nls` help page.

Comment: Take a look at the simple examples in this old answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15102307/496803 They should show you how to use nls with some pre-worked examples.

Comment: i just added the data

Answer (score 1):

Your example data doesn't seem well named, so I'll pretend I didn't see it.  Make a vector called `dose` that contains your dose information and a vector called `Y` that contains the Y variable.  Obviously they should be the same length.  I'll just use `rnorm()` for my example.  Then just call nls with some reasonable start values.  I'll just pick some out of the blue.

```
> dose <- rnorm(400)
> Y <- rnorm(400)
> nls(formula=Y~e0+((dose*emax)/(dose+ed50)),start=c(e0=1,emax=10,ed50=2))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ e0 + ((dose * emax)/(dose + ed50))
   data: parent.frame()
      e0     emax     ed50 
0.036105 0.005475 1.991276 
 residual sum-of-squares: 373.8

Number of iterations to convergence: 21 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.759e-06
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,  but may i know why e0=1,emax=10,ed50=2?
how did you choose those values

Comment: They were the first random numbers that popped into my head.  You could use all zeros if you wanted.  Initial values don't matter if the problem is well-behaved.  Even so, use something close to where you think it will end up if you can...or use zero or something else.  You just have to give it *something*.

Comment: how come when i try this the function does not work?
nls(formula=Y~e0+((dose^h*emax)/(dose^h+ed50)),start=c(e0=1,emax=10,ed50=2,h=2))

thanks

Comment: Don't know.  Try posting the output R gives you when you try as well as part, at least, of the Y and dose vectors.  You can get a postable output using the `dput()` command.

Comment: The response are multiple:one is this 
    Error in nls(formula = Y ~ e0 + ((dose^h * emax)/(dose^h + ed50)),            start = c(e0 = 100,  : 
    number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50

another one is this 
   Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
The code  is this 
    nls(formula=Y~e0+               ((dose^h*emax)/(dose^h+ed50)),start=c(e0=100,emax=100,ed50=20,h=10))

Y is too long but my dose is this
    dose <- c(rep(5,30),rep(25,30),rep(100,30),rep(250,30))

Comment: You might need to try a bunch of other starting points until you find one that works--or maybe just allow more iterations.  Your objective function looks a little bit nasty to me so the optimization is not trivial.