# How can I make a visualization of a time trend of a mean number against year?

Tags: r, time-series, visualization

Hey I want to make a visualization of the mean number of children a woman has against the years with a time trend.

I've tried

```r
mean_children_yearly <- aggregate(kids ~ year, fertility, FUN = mean)       
plot(mean_children_yearly, xlim=c(2002,2014),
      ylim=c(range(mean_children_yearly[,2])))
```

To get a visualization but cannot seem to add in a trend line
Futhermore I tried working with time series

```r
a <- ts(mean_children_yearly)
plot(a)
```

but that does not put the years on the x-axis. How can I get the years on the x-axis?

Comment: You could/should add the images/plots generated by your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742754/how-to-build-a-trendline-on-a-graph-in-r

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Make up a data set to work with:

```r
set.seed(101)
fertility <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2010, each = 5),
                 kids = sample(0:5, size = 55, replace = TRUE))
```

When you make the whole thing a time series, you get a plot of year vs index (silly) and kids vs index.  Assuming your data are yearly, this is a little more sensible:

```r
a <- ts(mean_children_yearly$kids, start = 2000)
plot(a)
```

but it doesn't give you a time trend.

You could do this to add a trend line to the original plot:

```r
m <- lm(kids ~ year, data = mean_children_yearly)
plot(mean_children_yearly)
abline(m)
```

Or, if you want to go down the `ggplot` rabbit hole:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mean_children_yearly) +
   aes(x = year, y = kids) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```